# Unity - ResolveAll by name with condition

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

I was wondering if it is possible to resolve all dependancies in Unity by some condition on the name that they were registered.

For example:
Resloving all interfaces registered where the name registered starts with "ProcessA".

And if there is no way to do this then perhaps how can i extend Unity to allow this.

Comment: Calling into the container directly is generally considered an anti-pattern. If you are able to supply more context to your question (what problem are you trying to solve), perhaps we can give you some tips about how to improve your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `Registrations` to do this and I would recommend an extension method rather than extending Unity directly:

```
var matches = c.Resolve<IMyService>(name => name.StartsWith("ProcessA"));
```

Using this extension method:

```
public static class MyUnityExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Resolve<T>(this IUnityContainer c, Func<string, bool> match)
    {
        var matches = c.Registrations.Where(r => match(r.Name));

        foreach (var registration in matches)
        {
            yield return c.Resolve<T>(registration.Name);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to Michael's answer, I extended that to allow you to register with the same names yet use resolve all to only resolve those registered against that name.

```
public struct ScopedName<T>
{
    private const string Separator = "|";

    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly string _registrationName;

    public ScopedName(string name)
        : this()
    {
        _name = name;
        _registrationName = name + Separator + typeof(T).FullName;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(ScopedName<T> scopedName)
    {
        return scopedName._registrationName;
    }

    public bool IsMatach(string other)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(other))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var i = other.IndexOf(Separator, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
        if (i < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return string.Equals(_name, other.Substring(0, i), StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    }
}

public static class UnityEx 
{
    public static IUnityContainer RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>(
        this IUnityContainer container,
        ScopedName<TTo> scopedName,
        LifetimeManager lifetimeManager,
        params InjectionMember[] injectionMembers) where TTo : TFrom
    {
        return container.RegisterType(typeof(TFrom), typeof(TTo), scopedName, lifetimeManager, injectionMembers);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> ResolveAll<T>(this IUnityContainer container, ScopedName<T> name, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides)
    {
        var matches = container.Registrations.Where(r => name.IsMatach(r.Name));

        foreach (var registration in matches)
        {
            yield return container.Resolve<T>(registration.Name, resolverOverrides);
        }
    }
}
```

Allows for registration and resolution like this:

```
        container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo1>(new ScopedName<Foo1>("Scope1"), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo2>(new ScopedName<Foo2>("Scope1"), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo3>(new ScopedName<Foo3>("Scope2"), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo4>(new ScopedName<Foo4>("Scope2"), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        var scope1Foos = container.ResolveAll(new ScopedName<IFoo>("Scope1"));
        var scope2Foos = container.ResolveAll(new ScopedName<IFoo>("Scope2"));
```

scope1Foos will container both Foo1 and Foo2, scope2Foos will contain both Foo3 and Foo4