# How to get all instances of a type by name from unity container?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a container with some registered instances like:

```
container.RegisterInstance(typeof(Interface1), "Mapping1", new Class1("1"))
         .RegisterInstance(typeof(Interface1), "Mapping1", new Class1("2"))
         .RegisterInstance(typeof(Interface1), "Mapping2", new Class1("3"))
         .RegisterInstance(typeof(Interface1), "Mapping2", new Class1("4"));
```

So how can I get all instances of type `Interface1` named, for example, "Mapping1"?
Calling code will be something like this:

```
var instances = container.ResolveAll<Interface1>("Mapping1");
```

Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that registering the instances like this is going to produce the results you want.  *RegisterInstance* registers an object as a singleton, so by definition you cannot have more than one singleton with the same name.  From the example provided above, *container.ResolveAll()* will only return 2 instances.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have multiple registrations with the same name and type combination. Each new  registration will overwrite the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method to handle this. Take a look at this post.  It helped me and I think it answers your question:
[Unity - ResolveAll by name with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926525/unity-resolveall-by-name-with-condition)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a new answer to this question I found in [this unity container wiki page](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/wiki/Difference-between-ResolveAll-and-Enumerable.), where, for the following case:

```
RegisterType(typeof(IService), typeof(Service));
RegisterType(typeof(IService), typeof(Service),  "Name-1");
RegisterType(typeof(IService), typeof(Service1), "Name-2");
RegisterType(typeof(IService), typeof(Service1), "Name-3");
RegisterType(typeof(IService), typeof(Service1), "Name-4");
```

> historically when calling `ResolveAll<IService> (Resolve<IService[]>)` Unity would only return 4 items, those with
> 'Name-x', but now, support for IEnumerable<> has been added. As
> opposed to ResolveAll, resolving
> `Resolve<IEnumerable<SomeType>>()` will return all registrations
> satisfying IService. So in the example above it will return all 5
> objects.

I know it's not the same code because you're registering instances instead of types, but it might help anyway, I haven't tested it.